# How to retrieve the last element that matches a condition in a list in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How do I iterate through a list and get the most recent value appended if it matches a certain condition?

For example:

z = ["hello timmy", "hello james", "goodbye barry", "goodbye timmy", "hello barry"]

How would I get the last item in the list "z" that contains "timmy"?

Comment: Which part of the task send to be the problem? Do you know how to check if "timmy" is in a string? Do you know how to find all items which satisfy a condition? Do you know how to find the last one?

Answer (score 0):

```
z = ["hello timmy", "hello james", "goodbye barry", "goodbye timmy", "hello barry"]
last_timmy = None

for item in reversed(z):
    if "timmy" in item:
        last_timmy = item
        break

print(last_timmy) # Output: "goodbye timmy"
```

we first define the list z containing several strings. We then use a for loop to iterate through the list in reverse order using the reversed() function.

Comment: What do you think will happen if 'timmy' isn't found in any of the elements of the list?

Comment: @Pingu if no element in the list contains "timmy", this code will raise a NameError because last_timmy will not have been defined. You may want to add a check for this case by initializing last_timmy to None before the loop and then checking its value after the loop has completed.

Comment: I was thinking maybe you would like to correct your "answer"

Comment: done : a variable named last_timmy initial value to None